# Unable to upload big files through form

Tags: php, codeigniter, server, web-hosting

I am using codeigniter and I have set the limit for unlimited file size also my server is showing max_file_size of 20MB in phpinfo() but I am unable to upload file > 200KB. I am on 000webhost
my code igniter code is

```
$config['max_size']     = 0;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uLvg.png
also When I upload the file without using codeigniter it is uploaded without showing any error

Comment: What's your `post_max_size` set to?

Comment: it is set to 20mb

Comment: So your phpinfo() shows both set to 20MB? What errors do you get when you try and upload your file? What permissions are set on the server's upload folder?

Comment: how do you know that the size is the error?

Comment: It is showing error:  The uploaded file exceeds the maximum size allowed by the submission form.

Answer (score 2):

Along with the `post_max_size` you need also adjust the `upload_max_filesize` parameter in the `php.ini`.

Comment: But the same file get uploaded if I don't use code igniter

Comment: @Shankar_edu Have you tried checking `$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());` when doing the upload? What error do you get? Are you sure the error is about the size?